# Is every language with a finite number of strings regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

1. Is every language with a finite number of strings regular?
2. Is the language of all strings regular?

I am new to this topic and got confused. Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: These are, in fact, the most trivial examples of regular languages (empty language aside) and you should find them in any book on the subject.

Comment: @abc13 A.Schulz answered the question, you should mark is as answered.

Answer (score 11):

1. Yes. Assume the language is $L=\{w_1,w_2,\ldots, w_n\}$. then you can form the [regular  expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) $w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_n$, which describes $L$.

   You can also argue with finite automata or regular grammars.
2. Yes, if your alphabet is $\Sigma=(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ then the regular expression $(a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_k)^*$ describes the languages of all possible strings over $\Sigma$.